# Hide address bar on inapp browser on react native without using webview

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I want to hide the address bar of inapp browser which gets redirected when I click on a link in react-native. How do I do that ?

Comment: Can you explain a little more on the "inapp browser" being use here in react-native? Im not aware react-native is having one, besides webview? Tq

Comment: Inapp bowser is a Chrome Custom Tabs for Android & SafariServices/AuthenticationServices for iOS.

pls check with this link 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. In return after some research, it seems that hiding the address bar with the use of SFSafariViewController is not possible and not meant to be do so.  https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ ((vii) SafariViewController must be used to visibly present information to users; the controller may not be hidden or obscured by other views or layers. Additionally, an app may not use SafariViewController to track users without their knowledge and consent.). Hope it helps.

Comment: Consider upvote the comment if that helps :)